# Error when trying to install phpoffice / phpspreadsheet package on e Laravel, I've tried several ways, but I can't find the error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Guys I am facing a problem to install phpoffice / phpspreadsheet via composer in laravel I use php7.4 in ubunto 20.04. Does anyone know how I can be solving this problem?

```
 Problem 1
        - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0].
        - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.15.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    
      To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
        - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
      You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: You have a missing php extension required for the package phpoffice "ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system" You need to install the extension on your system before you can install php office

Comment: What have you tried to resolve that problem? As this question has been asked multiple times, there are already tons of answers here